# Minimal slices for dividing $m$ pizzas to $n$ people is $m+n-\gcd(m,n)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, gcd-and-lcm, bipartite-graphs

The following problem is taken from *Graph Theory* by Adrian Bondy, U.S.R. Murty, crediting H. Bass.

> *m* identical pizzas are to be shared equally amongst *n* students. The pizzas are not necessarily divided into equal parts, and the slices of a given pizza may vary in size.
>
> > a. Show how this goal can be achieved by dividing the pizzas into a total of
> > $m + n − d$ pieces, where $d=\gcd(m,n)$.

> > b. By considering a suitable bipartite graph, show that no division into a smaller number of pieces will achieve the same objective.

Try the example of $m=6$ pizzas shared by $n=8$ students. We can divide each pizza into two slices of sizes $3/4$ and $1/4$, as follows:

[image: 6 pizzas shared by 8 students]

Where $6$ students will get one slice of $3/4$, and the other two will eat $3$ slices of $1/4$.
I am trying to formulate the idea of slicing each pizza into $n$ slices and "rejoining" some of them into a bigger slice, but I couldn't find the general algorithm for that.

Comment: Hint for a: Cut up the number line from 0 to $m$ at the integers (representing your pizza) and also at $m/n$ (representing which pizza part the student will get). Show that you get $n+m - \gcd(n,m)$ parts.